# Integration testing strategy resources

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, integration-testing

I am looking for resources on strategies for writing bottom-up, end-to-end integration tests. These tests will be for a large-scale C# .NET application that uses MS silverlight and ASP.NET MVC. The tests will be written in NUnit. I am new to writing integration tests and would ideally like a good 'one-stop-shop' resource or two that will help outline the process (conceptually) and ensure that I cover all the bases, and do so in an efficient manner using best-practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual NUnit seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I use WatiN (http://watin.org/documentation/getting-started/). It integrates with NUnit and it's very easy to set up.